# Group by 2 parameters from 2 tables

Tags: sql, group-by

My first question on this site is simple.

Is it possible to use SQL `GROUP BY` with 2 parameters from 2 tables

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT COUNT(a.id), 
  b.id 
FROM 
  table a 
  LEFT JOIN table b 
GROUP BY a.id, b.id
```

I add my complete request

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.PkID, e.LocID, e.LocationName, l.Name, e.LocationCity, l.City, e.Title, l.Descript, e.Description, e.LocID, e.LocationName, e.StartDate, e.StartTime, e.EndTime, e.TBD, c.CategoryName, Count(e.PkID), ec.CategoryID, l.PkID
                FROM events e
                        LEFT JOIN eventcategories ec ON (ec.EventID = e.PkID)
                        LEFT JOIN categories c ON (ec.CategoryID = c.PkID)
                        LEFT JOIN locations l ON (e.LocID = l.PkID)
                    WHERE DATE(StartDate) >= DATE(CURDATE()) AND l.IsActive = 1
                    GROUP BY " . $Group . "
                    ORDER BY " . $Order . "
                    ;

$Group = $Order = 'l.Name';
```

I display several l.Name, with for each one, number of events organized counted(e.PKiD)

Each event have one or more categories, when i have just one category it's the correct count but when i have for example one event in one location with 3 categories it counted 3 in place of 1 (event)

Comment: The first answer you get on this site is simple, too: the best way to find out is trying it in an RDBMS of your choice :)    (the answer is also "Yes").

Comment: I forgot to ask how to ? :)

Comment: c'mon, just run your query and check ;) It works

Comment: Like explained my query works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't mention what your query is supposed to do, it is hard to guess. The general answer to your question is "Yes, you can have `GROUP BY` by two parameters". This will create table going through all possible pairs of `a.id` and `b.id`. This is the answer to your question.

Now, returning to your query, it is just wrong (as long as you don't explain what you actually want to do with it) because grouping by `a.id` will always give `COUNT(a.id)` as 0 or 1 and `DISTINCT` will select only unique values for `COUNT(a.id)`; I doubt this is the expected behavior.

EDIT: After the question has been edited with a new query. Now I think you don't need two `GROUP BY` at all. You are counting each event multiple times because when joining on `categories` you get multiple records for same event id. You simply need to have a distinct count:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT e.PkID) .... GROUP BY " . $Group . "
```

Comment: What platform are you talking about here?

Comment: I'm not aware of any platform where group by two parameters wouldn't work... I could think of some (possible) discrepancies with counting NULLs though, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To count `a.id` per `b.id`, you could use something like:

```
SELECT  b.id
,       count(a.id)
from    TableB b
left join
        TableA a
on      a.bid = b.id
```

Where `TableA.bid` is a foreign key that references `TableB(id)`.

Comment: a.id and b.id are two differents things